# IllegalMonitorStateException in Spring DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter

Tags: spring, tomcat

Can anybody give me advice on how to deal with this problem?

I've detect that my spring-based web application doesn't work.
After sending QUIT signal I got the following stack trace:

```
"ajp-apr-8009-exec-8" daemon prio=10 tid=0x09962000 nid=0x91f runnable [0x7006e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Throwable.java:782)
    - locked <0x790a89c0> (a java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException)
    at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:250)
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:54)
    at java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>(RuntimeException.java:51)
    at java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException.<init>(IllegalMonitorStateException.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:247)
    - locked <0x88186b58> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1824)
    - locked <0x88c3b7a8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I cannot reproduce this every time but problem still present.